# How to escape colon character in json query using ansible

Tags: python, json, ansible, jmespath, json-query

Running **ec2_instance_facts** Ansible module and registering it to a variable called **ec2**.

I have tags on ec2 instance which has colon characters in its key name.

I can grab **environment** tag value using this:

```
 set_fact:
    number_of_nodes: "{{ ec2.instances|json_query('[*].tags.environment') }}"
```

But cannot grab value of **"aws:lc:sg"**, trying the following:

```
 set_fact:
    number_of_nodes: "{{ ec2.instances|json_query('[*].tags.aws:lc:sg') }}"
```

Also tried by putting \, \ , /, // characters before colon. Doesn't work.

Can someone help ? :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When wanting to escape `? : -` the ansible docs recommend quoting them with double-quotes `"`. (docs [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html#gotchas) In your case that's rather difficult as you should be using single quotes in the json_query filter.
You can try replacing the arguments of that filter with a var and later when you declare that var, you can use double-quotes.

```
 set_fact:
    number_of_nodes: "{{ ec2.instances|json_query(the_var) }}"
 vars:
    the_var: "[*].tags.aws:lc:sg"
```

I hope this helps!
Cheers!

Comment: thank you so much. adding single quote outside and double quote inside worked for me. 
    ' the_var: [*]."tags.aws:lc:sg" '

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Comment: Would be nice if you could edit the answer, as it doesn't work as in described in it, but only as in @sherri s comment